# Routine to saveas not working for xlsm, only with xlsx

Tags: python, vba, win32com

i'm trying to create a routine to unprotect and re-protect password protected excels to that i can use pandas to load the data into a consolidated dataframe.

Whilst the script works fine for .xlsx it falls over for xlsm where i keep getting:

> com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel', "Cannot access 'MYFILENAME.xlsm'.", 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)

After a lot of research into why the errors were occurring, i figured that VBA's this was due to the interaction between xcl.DisplayAlerts = False and the .Saveas method.

Microsoft seems to have a different default for Xlsx and xlsm (VBA enabled) workbooks.

I tried to code around it by adding a ConflictResolution = 2 parameter, whereby i force any prompt to be accepted but this seems to have worked for me saving the file without a password in the first routine but the second routine for loop will fail. 
This exact same code will work if i use filename IE the xlsx version . 
see below . if i run just the xlsx it works, just xlsm only second fails.

[image: XLSX runs both for loops successfully, xlsm only the first]

Doc referenced:

[saveas doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.saveas)

[displayalerts doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.displayalerts)

See isolated code below (original file names changed)

```
import win32com.client


filename3 = r"f1.xlsm"
filename2 = r"f2.xlsm"
filename = r"f3.xlsx"

for i in [filename2, filename3]:

   pw_str = 'PIM FINAL'
   xcl = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
   wb = xcl.Workbooks.Open(i, False, False, None, pw_str)
   xcl.DisplayAlerts = False
   wb.SaveAs(i, None, '', '',   ConflictResolution = 2)
   xcl.Quit()

print("done")

for i in [filename2, filename3]:

     pw_str = 'PIM FINAL'
     xcl = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
     wb = xcl.Workbooks.Open(i, False, False, None, None)
     xcl.DisplayAlerts = False
     wb.SaveAs(i, None, pw_str, '', ConflictResolution = 2)

xcl.Quit()
print(i ," done")
```

Comment: is there any further information needed/ that i should provide here?